# Show that integrals are equal

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

Let $f \colon [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a convex function. Then $f''(x)$ is a nonnegative distribution on $(0,+\infty)$ and hence it can be continued to a nonnegative mesure $\mu$ on $(0,+\infty)$. How to show that for any continuous function $\varphi(x)$ with compact support on $(0,+\infty)$ we will have
$$
   \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \varphi(x) \, d\mu(x) = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \varphi(x) \, df'(x) \; ?
$$
For $f \in C^2(0,+\infty)$ it is obviuous. Maybe I should find a sequence of $C^2$-functions $f_n(x)$ such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise, $f_n'(x) \to f'(x)$ in points of continuity of $f'(x)$, $f''(x) \to f''(x)$ in topology of $D'(0,+\infty)$, and pass to the limit?

Comment: Definitions are important here. What do these integral signs mean?  Lebesgue integral on the left, Riemann-Stiltjes on the right, or something else?

Comment: @user79365 Lebesgue on the left and Lebesgue-Stiltjes on the right

Comment: OK. As far as I know, the Lebesgue-Stiltjes integral is simply the Lebesgue integral with respect to the measure which assigns  $f'(b-)-f'(a)$ to intervals $[a,b)$ (or some version of that). So the problem is to show that this measure is the same as $\mu$. For example, by approximating the characheristic function of $[a,b)$ by trapezoid-like continuous functions, for which the integral with respect to $\mu$ can be related to $f'$.